# TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments

Tags: python

I have a TypeClass to make Class:

```
class MyMetaClass(type):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('call __new__ from MyMetaClass.')
        return type(cls.__name__, *args, **kwargs)
```

but when use it :

```
Foo= MyMetaClass('Foo', (), {'name':'pd'})
```

raise Error :

```
TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments
```

if Change it like :

```
class MyMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('call __new__ from MyMetaClass.')
        return type(cls.__name__, (), {})
```

it will works okey ! 
where is problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `__new__` method is passed *3* positional arguments in `args`; the class name, the baseclasses and the class body. The `cls` argument is bound to the *metaclass*, so `MyMetaClass` here.

You are adding another name to that sequence; drop the name, or remove the first argument from `args`:

```
class MyMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('call __new__ from MyMetaClass.')
        return type(*args, **kwargs)
```

or

```
class MyMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('call __new__ from MyMetaClass.')
        return type(cls.__name__, *args[1:], **kwargs)
```

The `cls` argument is the *metaclass object* however, so unless you want all your classes to be called `MyMetaClass` I'd stick with the first option.

See the [*Customizing class creation* section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) of the Python data model:

> These steps will have to be performed in the metaclass’s `__new__()` method – `type.__new__()` can then be called from this method to create a class with different properties. This example adds a new element to the class dictionary before creating the class:
>
> ```
> class metacls(type):
>     def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dict):
>         dict['foo'] = 'metacls was here'
>         return type.__new__(mcs, name, bases, dict)
> ```

and the [`object.__new__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> `__new__()` is a static method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such) that takes the class of which an instance was requested as its first argument. The remaining arguments are those passed to the object constructor expression (the call to the class).

where *class of which an instance was requested* is your metaclass (producing a class object).

Demo:

```
>>> class MyMetaClass(type):
...     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
...         print('call __new__ from MyMetaClass.')
...         return type(*args, **kwargs)
... 
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __metaclass__ = MyMetaClass
... 
call __new__ from MyMetaClass.
>>> Foo
<class '__main__.Foo'>
>>> class MyMetaClass(type):
...     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
...         print('call __new__ from MyMetaClass.')
...         return type(cls.__name__, *args[1:], **kwargs)
... 
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __metaclass__ = MyMetaClass
... 
call __new__ from MyMetaClass.
>>> Foo
<class '__main__.MyMetaClass'>
>>> # Note the  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ class.__name__ attribute here
...
```

Comment: is it beacuse __new__ is a classmethod ?

Comment: @ZeroDays: `__new__` is a `staticmethod`, actually, with `cls` being passed in explicitly by Python. See the [`object.__new__` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__). When you create the (meta) class Python automatically wraps it in a `staticmethod` object.

Comment: but in your exmp  Foo is Class __main__.MyMetaClass !!! but if use type -> >>> Foo=type('Foo', (), {})
>>> Foo
<class '__main__.Foo'>
name here is Foo not type ! why ?

Comment: @ZeroDays: I explained that; because your code passes in `cls.__name__` instead of `args[0]` as the name argument to `type()`.

Comment: when run your code in python 2 it return : call __new__ from MyMetaClass. but in python3 it dosenot return any thing , ?

Comment: @ZeroDays: I used Python 2 notation for specifying the Metaclass. In Python 3, it is part of the first line: `class Foo(object, metaclass=MyMetaClass): pass`. See the [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation).